# Location of gatling load test project

Tags: load-testing, gatling

Given I want to test with Gatling some micorservices project with one public API and every micro service has it's own git repository then what is the best locations for gatling load test project? 
I wonder if I should create separate repository for that or just create directory in public API project repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you shouldn't publicly publish your load tests if your API is public.

Just beware of not publishing virtual users credentials and the likes, those should come from the environment.

If you have some DDoS countermeasure (and you probably should), just add some exception rules.

That's exactly [what the BBC does](https://github.com/BBC/gatling-load-tests).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm using private company repo so it's not the case. I just wonder what is correct repository/directory structure with the meaning software craftmanship

Comment: Based on your link to BBC i should have separate repository for storing load test. If you change your answer to that statement then I'll accept it. BBC made there a really great work.